# Json output is different in restlet

Tags: json, jackson, restlet

Recently i use restlet to publish some info as web service. 
Same code host in jetty server, but in different server i got 2 version result.

I think when i call webservice "http://.....api/currencies.json" it will use jackson extension to convert result to json format, but i don't know why got different version.

Is anybody can help me to figure out the problem, thanks!

This is the code, and i use restlet extension:  json, xml, jackson, xstream.

```
@Get("json|xml")
public List<CurrencyInfoDTO> represent() {
   return ...;
}

@XStreamAlias("currency")
public class CurrencyInfoDTO {

    protected String code;

    protected String sign;
    ....
}
```

Output version 1:

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "currency": [
                {
                    "code": "CNY",
                    "sign": "¥",
                    "rate": 1
                },
                {
                    "code": "HKD",
                    "sign": "HK$",
                    "rate": 0.8145
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Output version 2:

```
[
    {
        "code": "CNY",
        "sign": "¥",
        "rate": 1
    },
    {
        "code": "HKD",
        "sign": "HK$",
        "rate": 0.8145
    }
]
```

The server for version 1 is host in amazon aws, and server for version 2 is my local machine for development.

What i think is the version 1 is output as an object and version 2 is output as array.

And i try to remove jackson extension in my local machine, it will output as version 1, so i guess version 1 is using xstream extension, and version 2 is using jackson extension, but why restlet use different extension to handle same method output?

Thanks a lot!
Rick

Answer (score 2):

The relative position of the Restlet extensions in the classpath matters. Trying putting org.restlet.ext.jackson JAR before org.restlet.ext.xstream one.

If using a WAR, you can also manually adjust the converter helpers order in the Restlet engine.

Comment: i'm using a WAR, i'll check it out what u said. thanks for replay.